# Transfer value of object inside array to another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures, mapping, javascript-objects

I have an object like this:

```
var animals_data = {
category : [
    {
        class : "Reptiles",
        animals : [
            {
                image1 : "some image",
                image2 : "some image 2",
                name : "Snake",
                description : "some description"
            },
            {
                image1 : "another image",
                image2 : "another image 2",
                name : "Crocodilia",
                description : "another description"
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        class : "Mammals",
        animals : [
            {
                image1 : "more image",
                image2 : "more image 2",
                name : "Cat",
                description : "more description"
            },
            {
                image1 : "image",
                image2 : "image 2",
                name : "Dog",
                description : "long description"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        class : "Birds",
        animals : [
            {
                image1 : "bird image",
                image2 : "bird image 2",
                name : "American flamingo",
                description : "bird description"
            },
            {
                image1 : "another bird image",
                image2 : "another bird image 2",
                name : "Atlantic puffin",
                description : "another bird description"
            },
        ]
    }

]};
```

I want to get the values of the firstIndex and put them in a different array. However, I am having a really hard time doing this. The code I did is:

```
for (var i = 0; i < animals_data.category.length; i++) {
var currentIteration = animals_data.category[i];    
var currentClass = currentIteration.class;

animals_array.push(currentClass);
};
```

When I run the code the error says: Cannot read property 'firstIndex' of undefined. Thank you for your help.

Edit: included the actual object I am working with. I have omitted some parts but basically, that's the gist. The values I want to put in a new array are the ones in the "class" property.

Comment: There's a problem with your object literal. Please build a working example.

Comment: Current code produces `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ]`

Comment: Drop `;` at the end of `for` statement: there should be nothing but whitespace between `i++)` and `{`. As it stands, you immediately finish your loop.

Comment: Edited it to include the object I am working with.

Comment: Still not reproducible with your example. `Uncaught ReferenceError: obj is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. Thank you Xotic750 for pointing out that mistake. My question is:

when I used:

```
for (var i = 0; i < obj.firstKey.length; i++); {
var currentIteration = obj.firstKey[i];
var currentIndex = currentIteration.firstIndex;

new_array.push(currentIndex);
};
```

The array was doubled (i.e two of each was added).

However when I replaced it with

```
new_array.push(obj.firstKey[i].firstIndex;
```

It runs correctly. May I know why there is such a difference? Thank you.

Comment: The results of both approaches should not differ. But nobody knows exactly what does happen since your provided data structure and the code that does process some (other) data do not match. >>... It runs correctly ...<< - I doubt it for both code snippets: (a) `for (var i = 0; i < obj.firstKey.length; i++); { ...` - last semicolon will prevent running the loop as intended; (b) `new_array.push(obj.firstKey[i].firstIndex;` - closing parenthesis is missing.

Answer (score 0):

The provided data structure had to be sanitized and any list structure
thats members just need to be transformed from one type/form into another,
is processed best by `map`.

```js
var
    animalData = {
        categories: [{

            class   : "Reptiles",
            animals : [{

                image1 : "some image",
                image2 : "some image 2",
                name : "Snake",
                description : "some description"
            }, {
                image1 : "another image",
                image2 : "another image 2",
                name : "Crocodilia",
                description : "another description"
            }]

        }, {
            class   : "Mammals",
            animals : [{

                image1 : "more image",
                image2 : "more image 2",
                name : "Cat",
                description : "more description"
            }, {
                image1 : "image",
                image2 : "image 2",
                name : "Dog",
                description : "long description"
            }]

        }, {
            class   : "Birds",
            animals : [{

                image1 : "bird image",
                image2 : "bird image 2",
                name : "American flamingo",
                description : "bird description"
            }, {
                image1 : "another bird image",
                image2 : "another bird image 2",
                name : "Atlantic puffin",
                description : "another bird description"
            }]
        }]
    },

    animalClassNameList = animalData.categories.map(function (category) {
        return category.class;
    });


console.log("animalData : ", animalData);
console.log("animalClassNameList : ", animalClassNameList);
```